# iOS PDFKit - width issue

Tags: ios, pdfkit

In my app I'm using PDFKit to display simple PDF's.

A PDF is presented on a ViewController. The PDF to be set to the width of the screen and no more. I set a constraint in storyboard for PDFView to be 'equal width to superview'. If the PDF is over multiple pages so the user can scroll vertically.

All seemed to be fine, works perfectly on all screen sizes expect iPhone SE / 5, where the PDF width is greater than the screen size and thus requires a horizontal scroll to view the whole document.

Not sure why the PDFView is greater width than the screen view when I've set a constraint 'equal width to superview'

Below is the code from one of my view controllers that presents a PDF

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import PDFKit

class DisclaimerViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {


@IBOutlet var pdfView: PDFView!



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Disclaimer", ofType: "pdf") {
        let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
        if let pdfDocument = PDFDocument(url: url) {


            pdfView.document = pdfDocument
            pdfView.autoScales = true
            pdfView.maxScaleFactor = 4.0
            pdfView.minScaleFactor = pdfView.scaleFactorForSizeToFit
            pdfView.displayMode = .singlePageContinuous


        }
    }

    // colour scheme

    //navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor(red:0.6, green:0.4, blue:1.0, alpha:1.0)
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
}





override var preferredStatusBarStyle : UIStatusBarStyle {
    return UIStatusBarStyle.lightContent
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)


}

@IBAction func back(_ sender: AnyObject) {


    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

}

Please note this is testing in simulator. Is this simulator bug? Or am I missing something?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I swear I would like to tie a large brick to Xcode and its simulator, and throw them both to the bottom of the ocean....

It appears to be a simulator bug.

When my storyboard was set up to view the view controllers as iPhone SE / 5 size, with no change to the actual ViewControllers, constraints etc, the iPhone SE / 5 simulator width of the PDFView perfectly matches the width of the iPhone/SE. No horizontal scrolling.

But if the storyboard is set up to view a larger screen size so the simulator for iPhone SE / 5 is made too wide, leading to horizontal scrolling.

Literally just changing how you view your storyboard seems to break the constraints for width in simulator.

I hope this helps someone else and avoid the same wasted time that I've suffered...

Comment: Hi, I'm having this same simulator issue. Does this bug persist even when the app is run on a physical device?

Comment: Hi Lewis, I'm afraid I can't remember for sure! However I don't think so